# Visual studio, xamarin, sql server for ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am currently using windows. I am thinking about to install ubuntu on my machine. But problem is i've to use visual studio, xamirin, ms sql server on daily basis for development. Is there any support for these softwares on ubuntu. For ubuntu there is IDE microsoft visual Code. But i didn't saw any where that this IDE is for .net development or also it includes xamirin. Please confirm me that these softwares are available for ubuntu??

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support for any of those products on Linux/Ubuntu. The .Net core was just this year released on platforms other than Windows, so it's not out of the question that these tools could work on those platforms in the future. But I would say it's so early in the process that it's very unlikely to happen anytime soon.

Comment: Xamarin has not announced any plans to support Linux at this point.